# How to get all data from a gtk treeview/liststore in C?

Tags: c, treeview, gtk, logfile

I want to know how to get all data from a gtk treeview (row and column) and put it in a logfile, I know how to create the log, my problem is getting all data, I already know how to get the selected row, but not all rows at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gtk_tree_model_foreach is your friend.